# Return the earliest time for each day

Tags: excel

I have this set of data:

```
    A        B 
1  1/1/15   6:05am
2  1/1/15   10:00am
3  1/2/15   6:10am
4  1/2/15   11:58am
```

Data in column A is a valid Excel date field and data in column B is valid Excel time field.

What I am trying to get is the time of the first call per day. Example:

```
1/1/15 6:05am
1/2/15 6:10am
```

I have tried PivotTables with sort and groups but that did not work. Any ideas/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Pivot tables would work great to solve your problem.  Did you encounter any trouble using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C1 copied down to suit please try:

```
=MIN(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However a PivotTable could well be a suitable alternative:

[image: SO29269256 example]

Comment: pnuts, thanks for both the suggestions. For some reason the pivot table option showing "min of time" is different for Excel on the Mac vs windows. It works great though.