# First event of each day, but could be after midnight

Tags: excel, time, pivot

I have quite a big data set in this format

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 16/06/2020 | 9:49:36 PM |
| 17/06/2020 | 10:15:47 PM |
| 17/06/2020 | 01:15:47 AM |

Data in column A is a valid Excel date field and data in column B is valid Excel time field.

What I am trying to get is the time of the first call per day. I have tried PivotTables with min time but that did not work because it would pick the AM time over the PM time.  The data usually starts in the evening (PM) and goes on all night (AM). BUT, sometimes it wouldn't start until after midnight (AM) so I need it to pickup on that as well... Tricky one?

I'm getting a headache... Any ideas/suggestions are **most** welcome.

Comment: What is your start time of evening?

Comment: So, briefly, you want the earliest time for any date and that will always be after midnight.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return the earliest time for each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269256/return-the-earliest-time-for-each-day)

Comment: Create an auxiliary column beside the `Column B` and use a running `COUNTIF()` on date. Next create a pivot table, and keep the newly created `Column C` values in `Filters` area of Pivot Table and filter it with `1` so you will always get the `earlier times/first event of each day` when using a Pivot Table. Simply using pivot table and selecting summarize as `Min` will not return in your scenario. I have tested so I am suggesting.

Comment: @Harun24hr evenings can start anytime after 4pm

Comment: @SolarMike No sorry for not clarifying enough, the time can be before or after midnight. But it'll be from evening onward. I saw that post you suggested and it came close! But I ran into the AM/PM problem with pivots

Comment: Thank you @MayukhBhattacharya, could you please be more detailed? What are the criteria for countif() if I range it to the date column?

Comment: As for dealing with midnight, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319003/4961700

Comment: @Titia for the `COUNTIF()` on date, assuming the date values in `Column A` and starts from cell `A2`, then the formula in `Column C` in cell `C2` onwards will be `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)` this will give you a running count, so for the first occurrence it will be `1`, second `2` so on so forth. Now when you pivot the whole data, keep the `Column C` values in `Filters` and filter with `1` you will get the desired output, when the date is in `Rows` and time in `Values` area summarize as `Min`. Check **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/vSiWUQ6)**

Comment: @Titia Can you please give a try to my answer.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks for the explanation! It could've been perfect, however the values in column C are highly irregular. See https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApBHP0a2u0lMgdIDBlgMLkyOxjwQvA?e=u9LFHu

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya NAILED IT!!

Answer (score 1):

Formula I have used-

```
D1=UNIQUE(A1:A3)
E1=TAKE(SORT(FILTER($A$1:$B$3,($A$1:$A$3>=D1)*($B$1:$B$3>=TIME(16,0,0))),{1,2},{1,-1}),1,-1)
```

All in one formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A1:A3),
BYROW(UNIQUE(A1:A3),
LAMBDA(x,
TAKE(SORT(FILTER($A$1:$B$3,($A$1:$A$3>=x)*($B$1:$B$3>=TIME(16,0,0))),{1,2},{1,-1}),1,-1
))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I get #NAME? with D1=UNIQUE(A1:A3) and "That function isn't valid." with the E1 formula. I'm using Excel for Mac version 16.73, is there a plugin I need to install?

Comment: You need `Excel-365` to use these functions. May be you are using `Excel-2016`.

Comment: I managed to get the Take function to work, but the unique function is just not available on my excel. However Google suggested using the OFFSET formula as an alternative, are you familiar with that one? Much appreciated!

Comment: I managed to get both functions to work in an online version of Excel! Am I correct to assume that the values in D and E represent the first event of that day?

Comment: Unfortunately there's something not wright, as it's just making up times and never shows AM to be the first event, while that does happen. See screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!ApBHP0a2u0lMgdIM_A5anDVdPgg2oQ?e=ipQcbm I'm sure I'm missing something?

Comment: Can you share a sample file via onedrive or google drive.